# Using userdata in Cloudformation

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add some simple bash commands in my userdata but it looks like they do not run?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
RHELInstance:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Properties: 
  IamInstanceProfile: Super-Agent
  ImageId: ami-26ebbc5c
  KeyName: Super-Agent
  InstanceType: m4.large
  SecurityGroupIds:
    - sg-XXXXXX
  SubnetId: subnet-XXXXXXX
  BlockDeviceMappings:
  -
    DeviceName: "/dev/sda1"
    Ebs:
      VolumeSize: 24
      VolumeType: gp2
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: 
      !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        yum update -y
        cd /tmp
        wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/debian_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.deb
        sudo dpkg -i amazon-ssm-agent.deb
        sudo start amazon-ssm-agent
        mkdir /tmp/folder/
  Tags:
  - Key: Name
    Value: RHEL07102.00
```

Outputs:
  PrivateIP:
    Value: !GetAtt RHELInstance.PrivateIp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `ami-26ebbc5c`, which is *RHEL-7.4_HVM-20180103-x86_64-2-Hourly2-GP2*.

Most likely (but I could be wrong), cloud-init (which processes the User Data) is not installed on this AMI. As a result, nothing is looking at the User Data.

You could install cloud-init with:

```
yum install cloud-init
```

However, this would have to be done manually, and then a new AMI generated.

Alternatively, you could use Amazon Linux or Ubuntu, both of which have cloud-init installed by default.

Comment: You are right, it worked when I used the Amazon Linux image but I am still have a hard time trying to figure why it is not working. If I add the script to UserData in the AWS Console for RHEL it works - which means it must install or have cloud-init installed during boot up.

Comment: You can check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see if anything ran.

Comment: nice catch! didn't think about that.